# How to get records based on time?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDb and would appreciate some help with this query. I wrote the following aggregation pipeline. I wrote a query which returns last 24 hours records after that I am getting (00:01) hour to (05:00) hour records. With this how can I get records between (20:00) hour and (23:59) hours. Anyone, please suggest me.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {createDate: {$gte: new Date(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24))}}},
  {
    $project: {
        hour:    { $hour: "$createDate" },
        minutes: { $minute: "$createDate" },
      }
  },
  { 
    $match: {
      $and: [{"hour": { "$gte" : 0}},{"minutes":{ "$gte" : 1}}],
      $and: [{"hour": { "$lte" : 5}}],
    }
  },
])
```

Output:

```
{
  "hour" : 0
  "minutes" : 1
}

/* 2 */

{
  "hour" : 4
  "minutes" : 2
}
```

Expected output:

```
{  
  "hour" : 0
  "minutes" : 1
}

/* 2 */

{
  "hour" : 4
  "minutes" : 2
},
{
  "hour" : 4
  "minutes" : 59
}
```

and

```
{  
  "hour" : 20
  "minutes" : 1
}

/* 2 */

{
  "hour" : 22
  "minutes" : 2
},
{
  "hour" : 23
  "minutes" : 59
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `{hour: {$gte: 20, $lt: 24}}`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on JohnnyHK's comment, this `$match` should work for 20:00 - 23:59.

```
// 20:00 - 23:59
{ 
  $match: { 
    hour: { $gte: 20, $lt: 24 }
  }
}
```

If you want to get back both at the same time, you can use `$or` to include all of the criteria.

```
{ 
  $match: { 
    $or: [
      < 0-5 hour criteria >,
      < 20-24 hour criteria >
    ]
  }
}
```

---

#### Variations on 0-5 Hours

```
// 00:00 - 04:59
{ 
  $match: { 
    hour: { $gte: 0, $lt: 5 } 
  }
}

// 00:01 - 04:59
{ 
  $match: { 
    $or: [
      { hour: 0, minutes: { $gt: 0 }}, // 00:01 - 00:59
      { hour: { $gt: 0, $lt: 5 }}      // 01:00 - 04:59
    ]
  }
}

// 00:01 - 05:00
{ 
  $match: { 
    $or: [
      { hour: 0, minutes: { $gt: 0}},  // 00:01 - 00:59
      { hour: { $gt: 0, $lt: 5 }},     // 01:00 - 04:59
      { hour: 5, minutes: 0}           // 05:00
    ]
  }
}

// 00:00 - 05:00
{ 
  $match: { 
    $or: [
      { hour: { $gte: 0, $lt: 5 }},    // 00:00 - 04:59
      { hour: 5, minutes: 0 }          // 05:00
    ]
  }
}
```

---

#### Putting it all together

```
// 00:01 - 04:59 AND 20:00 - 23:59
{ 
  $match: { 
    $or: [
      { hour: 0, minutes: { $gt: 0}},  // 00:01 - 00:59
      { hour: { $gt: 0, $lt: 5 }},     // 01:00 - 04:59
      { hour: 5, minutes: 0},          // 05:00
      { hour: { $gte: 20, $lt: 24 }}   // 20:00 - 23:59
    ]
  }
}
```